# Why auto negotiation cannot be disabled on Fiber Port

Tags: juniper, autonegotiation

I tried to disable auto-negotiation in my Juniper ACX-2200 , but it says

```
edit#set interfaces ge-0/1/0 gigaether-options no-auto-negotiation

raki@# commit 
[edit interfaces ge-0/1/0]
'gigether-options'
Autonegotiation shouldnt be disabled for Fiber media type
error: configuration check-out failed
```

The Documentation says I need to manually set the speed and duplex,
I did set duplex to full deplex and speed to 1g both the sides, but it still gives me same error.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145316/discussion-on-question-by-r-raki-why-auto-negotiation-cannot-be-disabled-on-f); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.